# Loading a new page with sliding animation in Silverstripe 3 (with Ajax?)

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, silverstripe

I'm working with SilverStripe to build up a new website for a client and now I have the following problem:

Each page (and the children of these pages) will have a specific background image and I want that theses background images slide to the side when a new page is loaded instead of loading the whole page as usual (here you can see an example of what I mean: http:// www.thenomadhotel.com/). I guess I have to do that with Ajax or is there a better solution? Since I'm not so familiar with Ajax, my big question is: How do I work with Ajax in SilverStripe? Which code should go in which file? Can anyone help me with this issue? I'm not the super-programmer but a fast learner, so any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lots of work to do.

basically, you'll need to create a template for your pages to be loaded via ajax, containing only the content you'll update on page change, so no `<header>` etc.

next, see http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/3.1/reference/templates#calling-templates-from-php-code on how to render them (`Director::is_ajax()` is your friend here).

on the client side, you might want to go with jquery's ajax functions and catch all internal links on your page, loading them with ajax. 
simple code example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var $a = $(this);
        var href = $a.attr('href');
        $('body').load(href);
        e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

this snippet will load any links with ajax and replace the content of the current page's `<body>` with the loaded html. you should definitly have a closer look at jquery's ajax capabilities, there's a lot to learn: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

as for your 'sliding background image', what you could do is to prepare 2 containers in your `<body>`, one holding the background image, the other for the page's content (to be replaced using ajax). then, whenever a link is clicked, make the ajax call as shown before, then slide the background image.

these are just some pointers into the right direction - as i said before, lots of work to do.

in case you'd like to completely avoid this whole ajax stuff, another option might be to have your page's content inside in iframe - but that's another story.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer! That were exactly the hints I needed! I have already achieved what I wanted in a very simple version. Now I have to adjust some things to get the look and functions of the website like they were before..I hope you do not mind when I ask you again, if I get stuck..thanks again!

Comment: Hi..could you please help me to understand the next steps? I have now a page which loads the content with ajax and slide the background image if you click on a menu link..but I still don't know how to get the next background image (..at the moment I just slide the same picture..). where should I put the code of the background image? outside the ajax/content template? and how can I get it?

Comment: this is how the background image code looks like:  <div id="BgSlideWrapper" style="position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 0px;margin: 0 auto;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 1;">  
  <div id="slideInner">  
   <div id="BgContainer" class="slide" style="background : url($Photo.URL) no-repeat 0 0 #fff;background-size:cover;"> </div>  
  </div>  
 </div>

Comment: when I slide the image I just copy the div tag with the id "BgContainer" and set it right to the original div (out of sight) and than slide both to the left side ($('#slideInner').animate({marginLeft: -screenwidth}) and delete the first one when the animation is ready.

Comment: sry, busy with client work atm. you might want to put a script tag inside the loaded html, containing the new image?

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering you again..first: thank you very much! I solved the background issue! but one last question is left: how can I change the url in the browser window for each page on ajax load so that the user get the impression that something has changed and a new page was "loaded"?

Comment: use history.pushState, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: awesome! thank you very much for helping me through all these things! you are the hero of my day! ;)

Comment: arghh..sorry, there is still one problem left..I just noticed that I get an error when trying to access the admin page:

[Error] Couldn't run query: SELECT DISTINCT count(DISTINCT "SiteTree_Live"."ID") AS "0" FROM "SiteTree_Live" WHERE (ParentID = () AND Sort <= ()) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND Sort <= ())' at line 1
/homepages/23/d50733656/htdocs/webnew/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php:580 

Do you know how to deal with that? I guess this is due to my using of ajax?

Comment: did you run dev/build? can't see what this might have to do with your use of ajax - you'r accessing /admin directly in the browser, no? anyway, this is already far from your original question; 
if you still experience issues, please open a new one.

Comment: I found the error in my jquery code and solved it..but also found another issue, so I opend a new question.. thank you for never ignoring my cries for help ;)