# Ajax Template in Silverstripe and internal links

Tags: ajax, jquery, load, silverstripe

I recently posted a question on how to load a new page with Ajax in SilverStripe 3 while the background image (depending on the side) changes like in a slideshow when the user clicked on a menu item. The questions and the helpful answer can be found here: [Loading a new page with sliding animation in Silverstripe 3 (with Ajax?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471187/loading-a-new-page-with-sliding-animation-in-silverstripe-3-with-ajax/18483527?noredirect=1#comment28143111_18483527) .

I already have built up the website like suggested in the previous post and everything seems to work well, except for one thing:

When I click on a link within my Ajax template the page loads in the normal way and not through Ajax as desired. (This happens for example when I have a blog or team structure like it is described here:http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site or when a page have a link to another page of my website) Is it possible to change this somehow? I wanted to load the pages always through Ajax. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you're adding a click handler to the links the way [i suggested in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18483527/176140):

```
$('a').click(function(){...});
```

but when you're loading fresh html via ajax, the click event isn't bound (as this already happened).

you might want to use event delegation here:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){...});
```

this way the event is always fired, as it's always bubbling up to the body.

Comment: Nice! thanks! now I need to exclude external links and the links which open in a new window...I read something about it..how to do that but unfortunately can't find the link anymore :/

Comment: you could simply add a class to the anchor tags to identify the link type, and select them using 'a.external' or similar?

Comment: I just tried: $('body').on('click', 'a:not([target="_blank"])', function(e){...}); seems to work now like expected..yay! :)